# Prove that if $-2 \leq x_0 \leq 2$, then $-2 \leq 3x_0 - x_0^3 \leq 2$.

Tags: inequality, induction, recursion

Given $-2 \leq x_0 \leq 2$, I have to prove $-2 \leq x_n \leq 2$, where $x_n = 3x_{n - 1} - x_{n - 1}^3$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. I thought this problem can be solve by mathematical induction, but I can't prove the initial step, i.e., $n = 1$.

I try this two ways:

**1st.** If $-2 \leq x_0 \leq 2$, then $-6 \leq 3x_0 \leq 6$ and $-8 \leq x_0^3 \leq 8$. But, this provied the inequality

\begin{equation}
   -14 \leq 3x_0 - x_0^3 \leq 14,
\end{equation}

that its true.

**2nd.** I try prove it separately, with $0 \leq x_0 \leq 2$ first, but its wrong too.

How can I prove it?

Comment: Can you fix the title. The title reads that $$0\le3x-x^3$$ it should read $$-2\le3x-x^3$$

Comment: Yes, that its the problem

Comment: how did you arrive at the interval that you need to use for your inductive step?

Comment: Its given by the problem.

Comment: is the formula $$3x-x^3$$ also given in the problem? Or did you derive it?

Comment: All the formulas are given by the problem. My propuse is the mathematical induction.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy $3(-2)-(-2)^3=-6+8=2$

Comment: (Cubic map) Consider the map $x_{n + 1} = 3x_n - x_n^3$. Try to explain the dramatic difference between the orbits found with $x_0 = 1.9$ and $x_0 = 2.1$. For instance, can you prove that the orbit with $x_0 = 1.9$ will remain bounded for all $n$? Or that $|x_n| \to \infty$ with $x_0 = 2.1$?

Comment: @Empy2 Dang! You are right! My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an elementary way to prove this using AM-GM. If $x^2<3$, then

$$
\left( x(3-x^2) \right)^2 
=\frac{1}{2}  2x^2 \cdot (3-x^2) \cdot (3-x^2)\\
\leqslant \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2x^2+3-x^2+3-x^2}{3} \right)^3 =4.
$$

If $x^2\ge 3$, then
$$
\left( x(3-x^2) \right)^2 
=x^2 \cdot (x^2-3)^2  \leqslant 4\cdot 1^2=4.
$$

Comment: How can I prove the inferior limit in this ways?

Comment: I edited. Just square everything.

Comment: Your forgot square the last 2.

Comment: Doesn't AM-GM require all terms be positive?  What if $3-x^2 < 0$?

Comment: Thanks, tajiri_numero_1
@fleablood Good point, I just fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=3x-x^3 \implies f'(x)=3-3x^2, f'(x)=0 \implies x=0,\pm 1$$
So
$$f_{max}=f(1)=2, f(2)=-2, f(0)=0 \implies -2\le f(x) \le 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $f(x)+2$ is positive,  and $f(x)-2$ is negative.  Hint: factors